# implicit json converter in scala is null at runtime

Tags: json, scala, playframework

used play framework I have file with *case classes* (with aggregation Task in Project. it important) like

```
case class Project (var tasks: Map[String, Task])
case class Task (var activities: Map[String, String])
```

and in another file *trait* for converting

```
trait JsonConverters {
  implicit val projectWrite: OWrites[Project] = Json.writes[Project]
  implicit val projectRead: Reads[Project] = Json.reads[Project]
  implicit val taskWrite: OWrites[Task] = Json.writes[Task]
  implicit val taskRead: Reads[Task] = Json.reads[Task]
}
object JsonConverters extends JsonConverters
```

and in my service class something like

```
import support.JsonConverters._
class Service {
  def someMethod(json: String) = {
    val obj = Json.parse(json).as[Map[String, Project]]
  }
}
```

at compile time all fine. but in json parsing I get NPE inside json library
(`play.api.libs.json.DefaultReads#mapReads`)

`implicit def mapReads[K, V](k: String => JsResult[K])(implicit fmtv: Reads[V]): Reads[Map[K, V]] = Reads[Map[K, V]] {`

`implicit fmtv: Reads[V]` **is null** for Task class (for Project all fine)

I think it's because in `.as[Map[String, Project]` is specified only Project class, but not Task. But it is not exactly

I found 2 different solutions for this issue, but both is ugly for me

1) declare all implicit converters in **same** file with case classes. But I want to have all my converters in separated file. this solution is inappropriate for me

2) declare impicit for Task with **lazy** mod in `trait JsonConverters`

```
trait JsonConverter {
  implicit val projectWrite: OWrites[Project] = Json.writes[Project]
  implicit val projectRead: Reads[Project] = Json.reads[Project]
  implicit lazy val taskWrite: OWrites[Task] = Json.writes[Task]
  implicit lazy val taskRead: Reads[Task] = Json.reads[Task]
}
```

it works fine, and looks fine. but **I don't understand** why it's not work without **lazy** in **separate trait**? can anyone describe? or advise another solution

Comment: Initialization order is notguaranteed across different files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialization order of the trivial variables (`val`) and the lazy variables(`lazy val`) is different.

The `val`'s are initialized in **the order** they are described in the file.
The `lazy val`'s are initialized **on first access**.

In your case, the `Project` contains a `Task` so the `projectRead` needs the initialized `taskRead` to be done.

In your code, without `lazy`, the `projectRead` is declared before the `taskRead` so `taskRead` still `null` when `projectRead` needs it. That's why you got NPE.

*Still, the compiler can find the implicit `taskRead` and do not raise an error*.

Your fix with `lazy` works because `taskRead` now initialize **on first access**. Now, the `taskRead` initialize when `projectRead` asks for it. NPE is gone.

You can achieve the same fix by switching the declaration order:

```
trait JsonConverter {
  implicit val taskWrite: OWrites[Task] = Json.writes[Task]
  implicit val taskRead: Reads[Task] = Json.reads[Task]
  implicit val projectWrite: OWrites[Project] = Json.writes[Project]
  implicit val projectRead: Reads[Project] = Json.reads[Project]
}
```

Comment: Hi! very interesting... it was my first think about order of declarations. and this fix didn't work yesterday О_о but after your answer it's works fine! may be some classes was not recompiled in "hot swap" with play framework. thanks for detailed describing!